# Show script in parent top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have this script (is a popup):

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.setAttribute('async', 'async');
script.src = 'https://scriptexample.js';
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

When I put this code normally works well, but when the code is inside a iframe the code not works well and only is showed in the iframe.

What I need change in the code for make the call to "top/parent" location and show the script even if it is inside an iframe?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Main document and iFrame's document is a different documents and have a different variable scopes. The only way to archive this to use

```
window.parent
```

from iFrame to call scripts loaded in the parent window, and use

```
iframeElement.contentWindow
```

to access the scripts loaded to iFrame.

Read:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_frame_contentwindow.asp

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/contentWindow

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/parent

Example:

Having a `test` function defined in the main window, you can call it this way from the iFrame:

```
window.parent.test(...);
```

Comment: Thanks ZitRo. But how is the final code? I don't know what I need change in this code to show the popup inside a iframe. Thank you very much.

Comment: @JohnK. Please clarify where you need to store script — main window or iFrame's window.

Comment: to main window. Thank you!

Comment: Added a trivial example.

Comment: I'm sorry but Im not programmer. How is my final script code?                var script = document.createElement('window.parent.test');
script.setAttribute('async', 'async');
script.src = 'https://scriptexample.js';
document.body.appendChild(script);                                                                  This is correct?

Comment: @JohnK. ? Cannot help you as I don't know your context. You have to be at least little friendly with JavaScript to take the task you took. `window.parent.test` is not an element, it's a sample code.